# Example for SQL_TO_JSON

Tags: pljson

How to use the function `JSON_UTIL_PKG.SQL_TO_JSON`? Please give an example.

I tried this:

---

```
select JSON_UTIL_PKG.SQL_TO_JSON('select column from table where rownum = 1',100) from dual;
```

but the result is not ok

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of that function is:

`function sql_to_json (p_sql in varchar2,
                      p_max_rows in number := null,
                      p_skip_rows in number := null) return json_list`

Thus, the result should be a `pljson.json_list` object. Since the only information you have given is "the result is not okay" I can only assume you are expecting the result to be a JSON string. If that is the case, and your result is stored in a variable named `foo`, then you can use `foo.to_char` to generate the string. Or `foo.to_clob` to return the JSON string as a CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute as:

```
declare jlist json_list;
Begin
  jlist := json_utl_pkg.sql_to_json('select col1, col2 from mytable', 10, 0);
end;
```

This shows an error like "*jlist invalid left assignement*"...

Then I tried this one, and it worked:

```
declare jobj json;
begin
   jobj := json_dyn.executeObject('select * from myTable');
   jobj.print;
end;
```

It worked correctly!

Based on:https://github.com/oberstet/pljson/blob/master/examples/ex16.sql

Best regards